# Code only outputs a single row while trying to draw a rectangle

Tags: c++, for-loop, design-patterns

```
void fyllRektangel(int hojd, int bredd); 

    int main(){
        int hojd;       //Height
        int bredd;      //Width
        cin>>hojd;
        cin>>bredd;

        for(int r=1;r<=hojd;r+=1){
            for(int k=1;k<=bredd;k+=1)
                cout<<setw(4)<<"*";
            cout<<endl;



            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Why does my code only output a single row, but all the columns in my for loop? Im learning about patterns and the output is suppose to be of a rectangle where the width and height is input from the user.

Comment: Your return statement is inside your for loop.

Comment: @Ahmad Halabi What is the great idea to name a variable like  hojd and then in a comment to write Height int hojd;       //Height? Why do not initially to name the veriable height?

Answer (score 0):

your **return 0** is inside the first for loop.

```
int main(){
        int hojd;       //Height
        int bredd;      //Width
        cin>>hojd;
        cin>>bredd;

        for(int r=1;r<=hojd;r+=1){
            for(int k=1;k<=bredd;k+=1)
                cout<<setw(4)<<"*";
            cout<<endl;  
        }
       return 0;
    }
```